# Storing Line(2D) data in Navigation Data Standard format as geometry using SpatiaLite

Tags: spatialite, sqlite, navigation, standards

Is it possible to store Line(2D) data in Navigation Data Standard format(with coordinate bit shift) as geometry into SQLite and also make use of SpatiaLite functions for querying?

I have to use functions like MBRContains , Distance (without converting to WGS84 or UTM coordinates).

Currently it is stored in WGS84 format , but have to switch to using NDS coordinates
(using C++).

Comment: If you want to use those functions, you'll need to do the conversion every time you want to call them. spatialite functions work on spatialite geometry (or geopackage geometry, in some cases). You're probably better off doing the conversion on the way in and the way out, and getting the spatialite advantages; or using a C/C++ library (like geos / rttopo - those are used by spatialite).